# Why don't the Ministers of Magic apparate to the Muggle Prime Minister's office?

Tags: harry-potter

The entire question is in the title.  Instead of apparating they use the floo network instead.  Is floo arrival more impressive than appearing out of thin air?  Or maybe that's the point ... it's less frightening?

Comment: Spitballing here - but what happens if you apparate into a spot where someone/something is already there? If the PM happens to be standing where you apparate into, or you apparate into his desk?

Comment: It seems less part of the Floo *Network* as a single point-to-point access system, similar to the portrait access in/out of Hogwarts' and The Hogshead. Probably a security concern so would assumedly have had anti-apparition enchantments around it...

Comment: @phantom42 that seems like a whole other question.

Comment: Do Muggles know about apparating? If they don't, than making them think a fireplace is needed for wizard transportation is a cunning idea.

Comment: @phantom42 thats exactly what i thought when reading this question, you have to visualise the place your apparating into, and if say the desk swaps sides of the room, all of a sudden your splinched, in book 4 they have special apparating zones, an empty field, so people arnt trying to apparate in the middle of those 100s of thousands of people.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the same reason Dumbledore stated here:

> “Professor, why couldn’t we just Apparate directly into your old colleague’s house?”
>
> “Because it would be quite as rude as kicking down the front door,” said Dumbledore. “Courtesy dictates that we offer fellow wizards the opportunity of denying us entry.

Of course, the Prime Minister is a Muggle. However, the same courtesy is extended.

Comment: Yes but ... first, the painting of a Wizard was there in the Muggle Prime Minister's office to arrange (i.e., _force_) appointments for meetings, and second, the Ministers of Magic were, in fact, rude to the Muggle Prime Minister as a matter of course (the main evidence of which is that meetings occurred immediately as soon as the Minister of Magic wanted one and the Muggle Prime Minister wasn't given any choice; also neither Fudge nor Scrimgeour were exactly forthcoming with information or generous with their time and Scrimgeour was positively nasty).

Comment: And, too, both plumbing the Muggle Prime Minister's fireplace to the floo network without asking permission and installing a wizard painting with (apparently) a Permanent Sticking Charm are awfully rude.

Comment: Was the Prime Minister not given any choice? As far as I remember the painting announces the meeting and the PM accepts. Whether or not he actually could have stopped the meeting doesn't matter, the courtesy was given. Also, we don't know the fireplace was without permission - all Prime Ministers live in 10 Downing Street, perhaps an earlier Minister made the arrangement. Anyway, it's a matter of degrees - being short with someone isn't exactly comparable to kicking their door in. I imagine it's just a (rare) example of inter-wizarding politeness carrying over to the Muggle world.

Comment: I decided to make this the accepted answer ... even though I'm personally not exactly convinced the Ministers of Magic or the Ministries agree, my fellow scifi.stackexchange answerers do.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like it'd be a massive security flaw if wizards were able to Apparate into the office of the Muggle leader of a nuclear state.

Most likely, the Muggle Prime Minister's office is like Hogwarts, or the Ministry of Magic for that matter: impossible to Apparate into, but accessible using the Ministry-controlled and monitored Floo Network.

Comment: Wizards are already walking weapons of mass destruction, why bother with nukes.