# Why don't wizards and witches just apparate everywhere?

Tags: harry-potter

Why walk to class when you can simply apparate?  Why run from a pursuant instead of just apparate somewhere else?

Comment: The other question was about Hogwarts specifically, but the logic can be applied anywhere.

Comment: @phantom42 Shouldn't we close the other question because this one is more general?

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 This one doesn't currently have any answers, so I don't think it can be used as an original, technically. I could get behind it otherwise.

Comment: See also: [Why don't the Ministers of Magic apparate to the Muggle Prime Minister's office?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/84701/5184). Mermish Essence's answer addresses this a bit more directly with a quote from Dumbledore.

Comment: I disagree.  This question has broader implications than just anti-Apparation Jinxes or the risks of Apparating before properly trained.  An answer might also invoke the amount of magical energy Apparation requires, or risk of exposure to Muggles.  or canon indications that not everyone is able to learn to do it.

Comment: Directly apparating everywhere would be rude to the point. Just like Dumbledore says in the half blood prince

Comment: Also apparating is dangerous and difficult, most wizards prefer flying, floor powder and other forms of magical transportation